# OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file

Tags: python, pytorch, inference, tensorrt

[image]

```
OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file for '/root/autodl-tmp/llama-2-7b/pytorch_model-00001-of-00002.bin' at '/root/autodl-tmp/llama-2-7b/pytorch_model-00001-of-00002.bin'. If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint
```

Why do I get an error when I use `TensorRT-LLM’s build.py` to convert the `llama-2-7b` model?